# Visual Studio 2012 is Missing "Workspace Settings" Tab

Tags: visual-studio-2012

On the Team menu, Team Project Collection Settings, Source Control window there should be two tabs, "File Types" and "Workspace Settings".  Some of our developers do not have the "Workspace Settings" tab.  What determines if this tab is available?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a TFS 2012 feature, I think there might be a bug that's causing to appear on TFS 2010 instances. I'm guessing if you have ever connected to a TFS 2012 instance it will appear.

When changing the value in TFS 2010 it won't do anything. You just get the following error:

[image]